# sql counting based upon multiple values in other column - sql server management studio

Tags: sql, ssms

I have a table like below. I want to have distinct count of values in column usr for which pn is 2 as well as 3. In below case it will be 2 as usr =1 and usr =3 have values 2 and 3 in column pn. I wont be considering usr=2 becuase id doesnt have pn=3. How could i do that?

```
usr pn
1   1
1   2
1   3
2   5
2   2
2   8
3   2
3   3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select count(*)
from
(
    select usr
    from table_like_below
    where pn in (2,3)
    group by usr
    having count(distinct pn) = 2   -- this guarantees that usr have at least one 2 and at least one 3 in column pn
) T
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick.

```
select count(distinct usr) from (
    select usr from table t1 where pn = 2
    inner join (select usr from table where pn = 3) t2
    on t1.usr = t2.usr
)
```